# How to implement dropdown list change event catch function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropdown

I have in my html file this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-change="changedValue(selectedCar)" ng-options="x.license for x in fhu.carList" >
        <option value="">Select Car</option>
</select>
```

How and where to put the changedValue function inside my controller? I'm a bit new in this Angular and JavaScript so a concrete example would be nice. My controller is below and the dropdown list filling is working... [almost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361872/combo-box-filled-from-json-response-does-not-behave-normally). But that's another question, at this point the selection change function is more important.

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("fhu", []);

    app.controller("FhuController", function(){

        this.carList = cars;

    });


    $(document).ready(function(){

        var car = {};

        $.getJSON("fillingapi.php?action=get_cars",function(data){
             var i=0;
             for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                cars.push( {license: data[i].license, descr: data[i].descr});               

            }
        });
    });

    var cars=[];

    })();
```

Comment: Mention of controller makes me think, is this AngularJS? If so please retag appropriately as AngularJS. Angular tag is reserved for Angular 2+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question:  "Where to put changedValue inside my controller"
You already have by doing ng-model="selectedCar". Angular will update it for you. So in your controller you can do $scope.selectedCar and get the car that was selected from the drop down.

To explain a little:

- You're mixing angular and jquery. It's  not forbidden but it doesn't really add anything and might complicate things. They have different tactics on how to manipulate the view.
- Angular has two-way binding. You don't need to listen to when the document is ready. This is jquery code. Angular will update the scope and the view automatically for you.
- Also using this keyword in angularJS can cause some scope problems, use $scope instead.
- You're getting your data with  jquery's $.getJSON. You can use the angular $http component instead.

I've made a plunker with working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/1xqvFVTed9I7lJj9NkFH?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('fhu', []);

app.controller('FhuController', function($scope, CarService) {
    $scope.selectedCar;

    CarService.getCars().then(function(listOfCars) {
      console.log(listOfCars);
      $scope.carList = listOfCars;
    });

    $scope.changedValue = function() {
      alert('You just selected '+ $scope.selectedCar.licence);
    }              
});

app.factory('CarService', function($http) {

  const getCars = function() {
    return $http.get('https://www.rantakallio.fi/fillherup/fillingapi.php?action=get_cars');
  };

  return { getCars };
});
```

Lets go through the code:

1. I removed the function wrap.
2. I removed the jquery document.ready
3. I removed the jquery .getJson and used angular's $http component, which does the same thing.
4. I made a service for your http request. It basically wraps the request in a factory/serivce wich you can inject anywhere in your code. So if there's a nother controller that needs to get the list of cars. You can inject the CarService

Look at the line CarService.getCars(). getCars is a function in a factory named CarService. I made it return an simple promise, you need to use the $http compnent (its commented out).

I simply return the promise and unwrap it in the controller and put the value to my carList variable. When angular sees that the variable has changed, it will update the view for you. The same happens when you select from the select list. Because you put ng-model="selectedCar" in your view, angular will update the model for you. You can therefore use it in your controller to do something.

In the code example you can see that there's no need to pass the value into the function. You can just read $scope.selectedCar

Comment: ...but? hit me :)

Comment: Ok, mostly understood, but... My fingers were too quick :-) 1) I use "license" instead of "licence" :-) 2) My code ( "your code" above) for api call does not work, the dropdown stays empty... 3) In fact I had a similar code in my html file like this: <h1>Selected: {{selectedCar.license}}</h1> 4) Maybe I expressed myself a bit unclear, but the question is to perform another api call when the dropdown selection is changed. How to implement it?

Comment: Just in case you want to try it yourself, here is the whole path for the dropdown filling API: [http://www.rantakallio.fi/fillherup/fillingapi.php?action=get_cars](http://www.rantakallio.fi/fillherup/fillingapi.php?action=get_cars)

Comment: I've updated the code/plunker though to fix the http call that was wrong, but its hard to test since the rantakallio doesn't allow http calls cross domain (Allow origin).

Comment: Does not work, neither the short or the long version of the api call... The dropdown still stays empty. The short version of api call worked in the original app.js, because my html file is in the same directory as the php file. However, there's something else wrong, because it does not fill the dropdown, not with "long" call, not with "short" call.

Comment: Found a couple of typos. Now the api call responds 200 and the data is there, but not shown. Should the http.get result be parsed somehow into the array, like in the original example?

Comment: There shouldn't be any need, the data is in the format you wanted. Same properties. Have you looked at the console in chrome (ctrl+shift+i) too see if its logged there? In my example I put console.log to verify if the data was there :)

Comment: Yes, I've checked the console, the data is there and looks ok. Suddenly this started to work :-) Maybe there was some kind of page caching issue, since my corrections and extra console logs did not take effect. Some browsing history clearing was needed. Anyway, it's working now and I have a function where I can (try to) create next api call based on selection change. Thanks!